# Hugo Error template: _default/single.html:20:16: executing "main" at <$img.Fill>: error calling Fill: *resources.genericResource is not an image

Tags: hugo

### Prbolem

I put some of my images in `/assets/images` folder. Then in `layouts/_default/single.html`, I created a hero image section for different screen sizes, shown in the code below. The problem is that Hugo says "*resources.genericResource is not an image" while the type checking confirms it's an image. More interesting, it works if I add the below changes while Hugo is running in on my machine. But I stop and restart, it shows the error and doesn't come up.

#### Some notes

.Params.image: each post has the name of an image in the front matter like  `image: /images/bird.jpg`

Some posts don't have a hero image because of that I skip this code if `$img` is invalid.

Hugo installed via Choco:

Hugo Static Site Generator v0.78.2-959724F0 windows/amd64 BuildDate: 2020-11-13T10:08:15Z

#### Code

```html
<!-- layouts/_default/single.html-->
{{ $img := resources.GetMatch .Params.image }}
{{ if $img }}
{{ if eq $img.ResourceType "image" }}
    {{$hero := $img.Fill "568x400"}}
    {{$hero_sm := $img.Fill "768x400"}}
    {{$hero_md := $img.Fill "1024x400 q50"}}
    {{$hero_lg := $img.Resize "x400 q50"}}
    
    <style>
        .post__hero{
            background-image: url('{{ $hero.Permalink }}');
        }
        @media (min-width: 568px) {
            .post__hero{
            background-image: url('{{ $hero_sm.Permalink }}');
        }
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .post__hero{
            background-image: url('{{ $hero_md.Permalink }}');
        }
        }
        @media (min-width: 1024px) {
            .post__hero{
            background-image: url('{{ $hero_lg.Permalink }}');
        }
        } 
    </style>
    <div class="single-image post__hero"></div>
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

Comment: Your question provided exactly the code I needed. The same problem occurs with `.jfif`.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found it. The problem was that Hugo doesn't support image processing for WebP format. Some of my images were WebP. Probably because of that the two conditions:

```html
{{ if $img }}
{{ if eq $img.ResourceType "image" }}
```

were passed for WebP images, but the functions `Fill` and `Resize` created the error. So, I had to replace them with JPEG format.

Comment: It should now be able to handle webp https://gohugo.io/news/0.83.0-relnotes/